Proper way to create Hardware Profile in Android Studio to match the original device
This might be a simple question, but I haven't been able to solve it for 2 days:
How can I create a Virtual Device, which is the exact, perfect copy of my Samsung Galaxy A55 phone in Android Studio?
I want to test my Angular - Capacitor build on a Virtual Device, but for some reason, I see something completely different on my phone compared to the virtual device. I think it's not displaying the screen size correctly.
In the Hardware Profile, I can enter the screen size in inches and the resolution, but if I input the data from the official A55 specifications (6.6 inches, 1080x2340), I get a really big screen where elements that are 500-600 pixels wide look weird. I get the closest view to reality in Chrome Dev Tools, but I want to see exactly the same on the virtual device as I do in real life. How should I set it up, or what should I download? I thought the skins would be what I could download from Samsung's official site, but these are really just "skins" and have nothing to do with modeling the device's hardware...
